# Box2D JavaScript Set a max speed to an object

Tags: javascript, box2d

i have a group of dynamic objects in box2D, and they are being affected by different random forces and i would like to set max speed to each object (translational and rotantional speed)?

i thought about a hack, but i would like to know if the engine provide a tool to achive this.

thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

box2D.Common.b2Settings.b2_maxTranslation = 9000
box2D.Common.b2Settings.b2_maxRotation = 9000

Comment: there is a way to apply this rule just to a group of objects??

Comment: I think this answers your question. You should mark it as answered and ask a new question or edit your question to reflect your real needs